Look-up range with dynamic numbers of headers, where if header is applicable, to copy whole column and append
The objective is to create a mailing list table, each e-mail per cell.
My code cuts between sheets so it's more user-friendly hopefully.
There will also be a IF code for each "If Applicable" cell in the actual worksheet. As such, in Sheet 2 column K-N, the header could be there, or show "" instead (and hence unable to fit look-up).
The code runs for K = 11 for Header 1 to 3 for now. As cell "K7" skips to Header 6, which makes more intuitive sense to the user on the sequencing of Headers, it however seems to cause the code to not recognise and end there.
If I replace cell "K7" with Header 4, it will work.
I prefer to fix the code than mess with user-intuitive use.
How could I continue to search for Headers 4-last Header for each cell?
Sheet1 'Mail List'



Header 1
Header 2
Header 3
Header 4
Header 5
Header 6
Header 7
Header 8
Header 9
Header 10
Header 11
Header 12
Header 13
Header 14




abc@mail.com
def@mail.com
fgh@mail.com
ijk@mail.com
..
..
..
..
..
..
..
..
..
..


bcd@mail.com
efg@mail.com
ghi@mail.com
jkl@mail.com
…
…
…
…
…
…
…
…
…
…


cde@mail.com

hij@mail.com

..
..
..
..
..
..


..







..







…




Sheet2 'Build'






































Loadport ETA Notices for A
Loadport ETA Notices for B
Disport ETA Notices for C
Disport ETA Notices for D





Loadport ETA Notices for A
Loadport ETA Notices for B
Disport ETA Notices for C
Disport ETA Notices for D



build area
build area
Fixed Text Value but will not   match Headers so should be left alone
build area





Header 1
Header 1
Fixed Text Value but will not   match Headers so should be left alone
Header 1





build area






Header 2 (if applicable)
Header 4 (if applicable)
Header 1
Header 12












Header 3 (if applicable)
Header 5 (if applicable)
..11













Header 6 (if applicable)
Header 9 (if applicable)














Header 7 (if applicable)
Header 10 (if applicable)














Header 8 (if applicable)















Header 9 (if applicable)















Header 10 (if applicable)






Sub GetEmailAddressETA()

    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim lastColumnETA As Long, lastRowETA As Long
    Dim ETAeach As Range
    
    Dim k As Integer
    
    Dim cCell As Range
    Dim lCell As Range
    
    Set sh1 = Sheets("MailList")
    Set sh2 = Sheets("Build")
    
    Dim lastRowL As Long, lastBuildL As Long
    Dim lrg As Range, ETArng As Range
    
    sh1.Select
    lastColumnETA = sh1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    
    For j = 1 To lastColumnETA 'Intended to be dynamic for future-proofing
        Set cCell = sh1.Cells(1, j) 'Intended for each header in 'MailList' to be a criteria cell
        lastRowETA = sh1.Cells(sh1.Rows.Count, j).End(xlUp).Row 'For each header to have dynamic last row
        Set ETArng = sh1.Range(sh1.Cells(2, j), sh1.Cells(lastRowETA, j))  'Set range to copy if later found applicable
        
        sh2.Select 'change sheet
        For k = 11 To 11 'ideally, will be k = 11 to 14 representing column K-N
        
        lastRowL = sh2.Cells(sh2.Rows.Count, k).End(xlUp).Row   'for dynamic last row in look-up
        Set lrg = sh2.Range(Cells(4, k), Cells(lastRowL, k))  'set look-up range with dynamic range
        
            For Each lCell In lrg.Cells

                If cCell.Value = lCell.Value Then 'if cell matches sh1's Header

                    lastBuildL = sh2.Cells(sh2.Rows.Count, k - 9).End(xlUp).Row 'look for last filled row in column B
                    ETArng.Copy
                    Range(Cells(lastBuildL + 1, k - 9), Cells(lastBuildL + 1, k - 9)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 'paste sh1 range for applicable header, into column B

                    Exit For
                    
                End If
            Next lCell

        Next k
            
    Next j
    
End Sub

Expected Output, where ..(number) = email address in specified header:








































Loadport ETA Notices for A
Loadport ETA Notices for B
Disport ETA Notices for C
Disport ETA Notices for D





Loadport ETA Notices for A
Loadport ETA Notices for B
Disport ETA Notices for C
Disport ETA Notices for D




abc@mail.com
abc@mail.com
Fixed Text Value but will not   match Headers so should be left alone
abc@mail.com





Header 1
Header 1
Fixed Text Value but will not   match Headers so should be left alone
Header 1




bcd@mail.com
bcd@mail.com
abc@mail.com
bcd@mail.com





Header 2 (if applicable)
Header 4 (if applicable)
Header 1
Header 12




cde@mail.com
cde@mail.com
bcd@mail.com
cde@mail.com





Header 3 (if applicable)
Header 5 (if applicable)
Header 11





def@mail.com
ijk@mail.com
cde@mail.com
Header ..1212





Header 6 (if applicable)
Header 9 (if applicable)






efg@mail.com
jkl@mail.com
Header ..1111






Header 7 (if applicable)
Header 10 (if applicable)






..77
..55







Header 8 (if applicable)







..77
..55







Header 9 (if applicable)







..77
..55







Header 10 (if applicable)







..88
..55















..88
















..88

















Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.
Please create MD table with online tool Table Generator.

You've not told us exactly what your code needs to do though?  It doesn't currently do that, so we can't get that info from the VBA...

Welcome babyy! Read The Tour and earn your first badge!

... or use use this VBA code to create a Markdown table from your data and edit it into your question.

Thank you very much to taller and MT1! I've edited the post to do so.
@Tim Williams Ah I see, my code hopes to append accumulatively a bunch of different header-ed columns. If it matches Sheet 2's column K-N, it will build for B-E. Does this clarify?

I did something really stupid.
My code is actually already completed as per upload. My headers just weren't aligned because I was creating a formula conditional that made me miss it out.
Just wanted to answer my own question to ensure anyone stumbling across this code can use as-is. Happy to hear if any further optimisation to the code can be done.
